# pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime has stopped working

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I've installed pgAdmin4 v2 on Windows 7. The installation went fine and I could launch it successfully without any issue. After couple of days, now if I try to load GUI I am getting the error – “pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime has stopped working”. Log file shows below error entries:

```
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired>
2018-03-26 13:16:01,937: ERROR  pgadmin: Exception when checking for update
```

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version check was root cause of the problem as my network has restricted access. Disabling version check in application config settings (UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED = False in config_local.py) fixed the issue in my case.